# slide out 'mobile' type menu using jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Im trying to write a little script to slide all of a pages content over to reveal a hidden menu like this image from the facebook mobile site below.

[image: slide out menu example]

Ive tried to recreate this using the jquery ui slide function but cant quite get it to work, ive been using

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.slider').toggle("slide", {
        direction: "right",
        distance: 100
    }, 500);
});
```

which is half way there, but i cant quite work out how to take it further, im not trying to slide all the content over, just 90% as the image above so you can still see a peice of the main content, any ideas ? ive made a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pudle/ckNx9/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ckNx9/6/

It involved hiding the slider initially, then allowing the toggle to show/hide it as it is sliding by 180px.

Below is the modified CSS for the .slider.

```
.slider {background:blue; width: 180px; height: 200px; display: none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see the jQuery UI toggle slide effect shows/hides the entire container. You can achieve the effect you describe using a bit of jQuery alone:

http://jsfiddle.net/ckNx9/7/

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {
    if($('.slider').hasClass('out')) {
       $('.slider').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 500).removeClass('out');
    } else {
        $('.slider').animate({
            left: '180px'
        }, 500).addClass('out');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the easiest:

```
$('.slider').slideToggle('slow');
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/